# Workaround for accessing class type arguments in static method in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, inheritance

The following error

> Static members cannot reference class type parameters.

results from the following piece of code

```
abstract class Resource<T> {
    /* static methods */
    public static list: T[] = [];
    public async static fetch(): Promise<T[]> {
        this.list = await service.get();
        return this.list;
    }
    /*  instance methods */ 
    public save(): Promise<T> {
        return service.post(this);
    }
}

class Model extends Resource<Model> {
}

/* this is what I would like, but the because is not allowed because :
"Static members cannot reference class type parameters."
*/

const modelList = await Model.fetch() // inferred type would be Model[]
const availableInstances = Model.list // inferred type would be Model[]
const savedInstance = modelInstance.save() // inferred type would be Model
```

I think it is clear from this example what I'm trying to achieve. I want be able to call instance and static methods on my inheriting class and have the inheriting class itself as inferred type. I found the following workaround to get what I want:

```
interface Instantiable<T> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
interface ResourceType<T> extends Instantiable<T> {
    list<U extends Resource>(this: ResourceType<U>): U[];
    fetch<U extends Resource>(this: ResourceType<U>): Promise<U[]>;
}

const instanceLists: any = {} // some object that stores list with constructor.name as key

abstract class Resource {
    /* static methods */
    public static list<T extends Resource>(this: ResourceType<T>): T[] {
        const constructorName = this.name;
        return instanceLists[constructorName] // abusing any here, but it works :(
    }
    public async static fetch<T extends Resource>(this: ResourceType<T>): Promise<T[]> {
        const result = await service.get()
        store(result, instanceLists) // some fn that puts it in instanceLists
        return result;
    }
    /*  instance methods */ 
    public save(): Promise<this> {
        return service.post(this);
    }
}
class Model extends Resource {
}
/* now inferred types are correct */
const modelList = await Model.fetch() 
const availableInstances = Model.list 
const savedInstance = modelInstance.save()
```

The problem that I have with this is that overriding static methods becomes really tedious. Doing the following:

```
class Model extends Resource {

    public async static fetch(): Promise<Model[]> {
        return super.fetch();
    } 
}
```

will result in an error because `Model` is no longer extending `Resource` correctly, because of the different signature. I can't think of a way to declare a fetch method without giving me errors, let alone having an intuitive easy way to overload.

The only work around I could get to work is the following:

```
class Model extends Resource {
    public async static get(): Promise<Model[]> {
        return super.fetch({ url: 'custom-url?query=params' }) as Promise<Model[]>;
    }
}
```

In my opinion, this is not very nice.

Is there a way to override the fetch method without having to manually cast to Model and do tricks with generics?

Comment: Just a note that static members can also be Generic but you need to type the static function itself like `public async static fetch<T>()`, also seen in this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65804786/423171 (it may not be relevant for this specific question but it was for me when I google this error)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function Resource<T>() {
  abstract class Resource {
    /* static methods */
    public static list: T[] = [];
    public static async fetch(): Promise<T[]> {
      return null!;
    }
    /*  instance methods */
    public save(): Promise<T> {
      return null!
    }
  }
  return Resource;
}
```

In the above `Resource` is a generic function that returns a [locally declared class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#local-type-declarations).  The returned class is *not* generic, so its static properties and methods have concrete types for `T`.  You can extend it like this:

```
class Model extends Resource<Model>() {
  // overloading should also work
  public static async fetch(): Promise<Model[]> {
    return super.fetch();
  }
}
```

Everything has the types you expect:

```
 Model.list; // Model[]
 Model.fetch(); // Promise<Model[]>
 new Model().save(); // Promise<Model>
```

So that might work for you.

The only caveats I can see right now:

- There's a bit of duplication in `class X extends Resource<X>()` which is less than perfect, but I don't think you can get contextual typing to allow the second `X` to be inferred.
- Locally-declared types tend not to be exportable or used as declarations, so you might need to be careful there or come up with workarounds (e.g., export some structurally-identical or structurally-close-enough type and declare that `Resource` is that type?).

Anyway hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: This is interesting indeed! But yes, I feel I might run into a problem with the locally-declared type export issue. I will need to investigate that part further before getting back at this / accepting your answer :-)

On a side note, to me it feels like the Typescript guys should just allow for accessing type parameters in static methods.

Comment: Having the static side access the type parameters from the instance side unfortunately wouldn't make sense.  In `class A<T>`, the constructor `A` needs to be able to create an `A<T>` for any `T`.  That means that from the static side's point of view, the `T` is not a concrete type.  You can think of the static side of `A` like  `interface AStatic {new<T>(): AInstance<T>}`.  If you add other methods to `AStatic`, it simply doesn't make sense for them to have access to the `T` from `new`.  The scope of `T` doesn't make it there.

Comment: "In `class A<T>`, the constructor `A` needs to be able to create an `A<T>` for any `T`"  => not if we have `abstract class A<T>`, right?  [Also, this these kind of patterns are perfectly normal in languages like C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) (which, I know, is different from javascript due to the prototypical inheritance). F-bound polymorphism.... sounds like fun, I know

Comment: "not if we have `abstract class A<T>`, right?"  If the language had a way to refer to the abstract constructor type, then it would.  Even so, the absence of a newable signature for abstract classes still doesn't give the static side access to instance side type parameters.  This feels beside the point.

Comment: I think in order for it to work so that static and instance side had access to the same type parameters, there would need to be one static side *for each* instance side.  In C++ (and maybe C#?) that works because template metaprogramming actually generates new code for each instantiation of the type parameter.   In Java and TypeScript you can't do this because there's only one actual static side in the type system for each class.  I can imagine changing that, but it don't know if such a suggestion would be well received.

Comment: OK that just blew my mind, not sure if i follow. You're probably right on your last sentence though. On topic: will get back at your answer after I have investigated the export issue. Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz i get `Type '<T>() => typeof Resource' is not a constructor function type.ts(2507)`, how to get rid of it?

Comment: [Where](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBhNAZJBvAUE-SAZgK7DwAuAlgPbBIBK01xATogDwAqAfABQCU2PAREgARlHIsE5JPAA2IKFAZNWiISK0EA9ACokkkFXhJI5ABbUAJir07h2kTGJj5lU0ZNJ3kgFxInADaALpIALxIoQDcjk74Lm4ehuTGyUoAnmREEOTwFgIBAAos1GCUUBBcodya8U4suax0wMTy8gCEsfUEAL5x8fr4lMBGZMjmVrZI9gNOie6eIABuEIVIJWUVVTx1PSKN5M1Ire0dc9r98VcNTSx0jFDMbBDdfUhxCkoqALI2EPIkBAAB7kCDAaaPZ4cP7WAF8QS4eILZJedJQLKmQi5fLrTblSrsWEAmp7eqHY5QYgwCAsAB02LyBX4b0ucRu+GJ8jpvnI0SQOh0SC5oTiXIZOOZ-MFG1KBKqIpC3DiwAgAHdhf95AI6VAVmsWQKhfjtkStcqcL0gA)? Can you provide a [mcve]?  Possibly in a new question?

Comment: @jcalz I get a `error TS4060: Return type of exported function has or is using private name 'Paths'.` I figured it's because, if you don't explicitly state function's return type, it will infer it from what it returns. This function returns a class defined inside the function's scope, hence the error. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Same issue as @jcalz, did you find any work around on this since then?