# infer keyword to get generic type from base class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Consider the following class

```
class SomeBaseClass<T extends string | number> {
    ...
}
```

And the following conditional type using the `infer` keyword

```
type ExtractInner<T> = T extends SomeBaseClass<infer U> ? U : T;
```

With this, we can extract the generic type used in `SomeBaseClass` like this (this is from the docs, more or less)

```
type InferredString = ExtractInner<SomeBaseClass<string>>  // InferredString is just type string
```

In my slightly more advanced scenario, the following is the case

```
class StringVersion extends SomeBaseClass<string> {
    ...
}
class NumberVersion extends SomeBaseClass<number> {
    ...
}
```

How may one define a type `ExtractInnerWithExtend` such that it is the equivalent to `ExtractInner`? I.e.:

```
type InferredStringWithExtend = ExtractInnerWithExtend<StringVersion>  // InferredStringWithExtend should be string
type InferredNumberWithExtend = ExtractInnerWithExtend<NumberVersion>  // InferredStringWithExtend should be number
```

Using `ExtractInner` in this scenario will result in simply `string | number`, I was actually expecting to get either `string` or `number`, not the union type. Is this maybe a bug? Is what I'm trying possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ExtractInner` will work on the derived version of the types  with one condition: that you actually use the type in the base class in some way

```
class SomeBaseClass<T extends string | number> {

  private value!: T

  // Any of these will also work
  //value!: T
  //m(v:T): void {}
  //m(): T { return null as any }
}

type ExtractInner<T> = T extends SomeBaseClass<infer U> ? U : T;


class StringVersion extends SomeBaseClass<string> {}
class NumberVersion extends SomeBaseClass<number> {}

type InferredStringWithExtend = ExtractInner<StringVersion>  // string
type InferredNumberWithExtend = ExtractInner<NumberVersion>  // number
```

The reason for this behavior is the structural nature of the typescript type system, type structure matters more then the inheritance declarations.

Comment: You, sir, appear to be a true typescript ninja. I'd like to invite you to check out [a other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518125/workaround-for-accessing-class-type-arguments-in-static-method-in-typescript/52519934?noredirect=1#comment91981473_52519934) that I have, curious to see if you have nice insights

Comment: @MauritsMoeys 10x, I'll have a look but if jcalz gave an answer I trust he's right, he's part of the ninja squad :)

Comment: @MauritsMoeys had a look, I actually saw the question and upvoted his answer when you first posted it. Neither solution is ideal (yours or jcalz) but I don't think we can do better at present.

Comment: OK Thx, small follow up question. How did you know about the answer in this topic? By experience? Or did you look it up somewhere? If the latter, I'd like to know how/where, because it implies I could do better "debugging" myself

Comment: @MauritsMoeys I've been following TS feature by feature since v 0.8, I have tinkered with the compiler, and I usually read the PRs on the roadmap (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap). Answering question here was also a great source of TS experience :). I can't  recommend a one stop source for advanced Typescript topics unfortunately :(