# Static members cannot reference class type parameters.ts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this generic class and I want to use that generic parameters:

```
export class OperationResult<TResult>
{

    public success: boolean;
    public message: string;
    public result: TResult;

    constructor(success: boolean, message: string, result: TResult) {
        this.success = success;
        this.message = message;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public static BuildSuccessResult(message: string, result: TResult): OperationResult<TResult> {
        return new OperationResult<TResult>(true, message, result);
    }
}
```

but it show me this error for the `BuildSuccessResult` function:

> Static members cannot reference class type parameters.ts

How can I return a generic value on a static function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your static method should also accept the generic like this:

See TS Playgrond: https://tsplay.dev/rw2ljm

```
public static BuildSuccessResult<TResult>(message: string, result: TResult): OperationResult<TResult> {
    return new OperationResult<TResult>(true, message, result);
}
```

Since the static method can be called without class instance, the method has to be generic. You would's require `<TResult>` part if the method wasn't static, because in that case, `TResult` can be inferred from the instance.

There is a lengthy discussion [on TypeScript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24018).