# Incompatible types when using enum as generic type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider the snippet below. The idea is that I have provider implementations that extend a base provider, and each provider accepts a settings object that extends a base settings object. Each provider has also a **static** method to test those settings before they are passed to the provider (**the method is static due to legacy reasons and right now, making it an instance method is not an option**)

```
enum ProviderType {
    TypeA = 'typeA',
    TypeB = 'typeB',
}

interface Settings {
    commonProperty: string;
}

interface SettingsTypeA extends Settings {
    propertyA: string;
}

interface SettingsTypeB extends Settings {
    propertyB: string;
}

type SettingsMap = {
    [ProviderType.TypeA]: SettingsTypeA,
    [ProviderType.TypeB]: SettingsTypeB,
}

interface TestSettingsOptions<T extends ProviderType> {
    settings: SettingsMap[T];
}

abstract class BaseProvider<T extends ProviderType> {
    constructor(protected settings: SettingsMap[T]) {}

    static testSettings<T extends ProviderType>(opts: TestSettingsOptions<T>) {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented');
    }
}

class ProviderA extends BaseProvider<ProviderType.TypeA> {
    constructor(protected settings: SettingsTypeA) {
        super(settings); // Settings has the correct type here: SettingsTypeA
    }

    static testSettings(opts: TestSettingsOptions<ProviderType.TypeA>) {
        // do some testing
    }
}

class ProviderB extends BaseProvider<ProviderType.TypeB> {
    constructor(protected settings: SettingsTypeB) {
        super(settings); // Settings has the correct type here: SettingsTypeB
    }

    static testSettings(opts: TestSettingsOptions<ProviderType.TypeB>) {
        // do some testing
    }
}
```

While the basic classes, interfaces and mapped types are inferred correctly, the static methods are having an issue. See the image below from my IDE:

[image: Type error]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or why typescript doesn't accept it as a valid type. Can someone please help?

Comment: ProviderType.TypeA is not exactly a type. It's a value of an enum, so you are indicating the string value there....I'm not 100% sure but you may have to go to conditional types to solve this scenario. Enums will cause you sorrow if you try to use their values in the typing system.

Comment: `BaseProvider.testSettings` is a *generic* function but you really don't want it to be. You'd like `T` to be the same one as the in the instance, but TypeScript doesn't allow the constructor to access the generic type parameters of the instance; you're probably looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518125/workaround-for-accessing-class-type-arguments-in-static-method-in-typescript).  Let me know if that's what you want: it would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/oN5Rdm). Does that meet your needs?

Comment: @jcalz in a short answer, yes. My whole problem originates from the fact that I can't have access to `T` defined in the instance for the static methods. Ideally, I should refactor the `testSettings` method to not be static but time constraints won't let me do it right now, so I think your solution should work for the time being! Thanks!
by the way, feel free to post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have encountered, the static side of a `class` has no access to any of the instance side's generic type parameters.  In some sense it is not generally meaningful to allow such access, because there is a single constructor and multiple instances... a class constructor like `class Foo<T> {}` has a type like `new() => Foo<T>`; a single constructor needs to be able to create a `Foo<T>` for any possible `T`.  So the constructor itself has no specific `T` that it can access.

There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#34665](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34665) to allow such access inside the type signature for `abstract static` methods, should TypeScript ever get them.  Right now, neither `abstract static` methods nor static access to instance type parameters are permitted.  So you can't do this directly.

The obvious solution here is to make `testSettings()` an instance method, but you can't do that for whatever reason.

---

The next possible way forward is to make a generic factory function which spits out non-generic classes.  This is the solution presented in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52519934/2887218).  In your case it looks like this:

```
function BaseProvider<T extends ProviderType>(type: T) {

    abstract class BaseProvider {
        constructor(protected settings: SettingsMap[T]) {

        }

        static testSettings?(opts: TestSettingsOptions<T>) {
            throw new Error('Method not implemented');
        }
    }
    return BaseProvider;
}
```

The type parameter `T` is in scope everywhere inside the implementation of the `BaseProvider` function, including the static side of the locally declared class that gets returned.  Note that the `type` parameter passed in is used only to help the compiler infer `T`; I'm not using the value anywhere.  But you could, if you wanted to.

And now your subclasses won't extend `BaseProvider`, but the output of `BaseProvider` called on whatever enum type you want:

```
class ProviderA extends BaseProvider(ProviderType.TypeA) {
    constructor(protected settings: SettingsTypeA) {
        super(settings); 
    }

    static testSettings(opts: TestSettingsOptions<ProviderType.TypeA>) {
        // do some testing
    }
}

class ProviderB extends BaseProvider(ProviderType.TypeB) {
    constructor(protected settings: SettingsTypeB) {
        super(settings); 
    }

    static testSettings(opts: TestSettingsOptions<ProviderType.TypeB>) {
        // do some testing
    }
}
```

All of that now compiles.  Of course there are caveats.  The ones I can think of:

- something like `instanceof BaseProvider` will no longer work; not even `instanceof BaseProvider(ProviderType.TypeA)` will work, because there is no unique class constructor anymore.
- if you need to export `BaseProvider` declarations in a .d.ts file, you'll need to do extra work to annotate types; function-local classes tend not to be exportable cleanly.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#code/KYOwrgtgBACgTgewG4EsAmw4BUCeAHYKAbwCgpypcCBBKAXigHIAXfYaxgGjIquACF6TVgX5cSAXxIkUIZpgBmAQwDGhAMrBmzWQHMAzsR7kVCCBAQh4CAnFYAuKPuZw9AbknTZ8uMrVRNbT19PlpgAA95EDRDQJ0QAyMKKDxEW1ZqR2dXBI8pGTlFVQ0teIM+QQiomIDS4KSKVJtMVn4sl3dPEhESoIT9AFklPCFSZIBta1QMbDYAOlCAXUc44NDuCan0TD4Ftn5l2r7y-e587yL-LGBnVf6AeTwdS30AHiwoKtAarZm+AD4GuR9HV+itQQYhnhxlhFnlpAowCAVM8QFB+EoQb9MO9PpFvoZsbMCP8ABQ9RxYACURmMUCUACNsqpmFAVAAbTGGDFYxDTTBA5Jsl4uMAohBwUlNeQo4BoJwQ-Tg46DYYwxY00h05L5IUUZxKHQqKDyW6KgD8pJszCVlBuzDuBkeqLeWH+mu1epNAAtEAB3KAgYABgCicEQksYAy03oQ8pACFZKAgeHZwAgoHkaEYVI8XqgUh1dLgWjAcDRPOARPhJA5XNgfO2cDC+Oi3MxVcbM1JRN2oQ9yVMIGyYuYEqliBlWYVKuVZRCbGoA69+jAtlJIJVuagAHod0d51BvZifYRTOHgCiTWwj5hgHO1ou6br9cxDShjaaHYqrU9bdczRVZ0UBeV5e3mUJ3UFZI9ygNAECcMxCC-PRny6Ot9EJLtMEqVsakrIke2w4lgD2URlxMEU4FHcdpUvadN3nB9+gqCihVXddGOCbdYMdQxj0MZhvTPCUSyvHpbxLZiTlENC6QNI0TXtPjfxtSllMVYDQPAggyIEKCxi9WD4MQjMlOcVCiwkIA)