# typescript define function argument type in abstract class

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance

I want to be able to use a static method like this:

```
UpdateUrlAction.send('https://google.com')

UpdateCountAction.send(3)
```

I want to define that UpdateUrlAction.send only takes a string as the parameter, but UpdateCountAction accepts a number. The solution should be based on this general structure:

```
export default abstract class ChromeMessageAction {
    static action: string

    public static send(payload: Object|string|number) {
        ChromeMessageService.send(this.action, payload)
    }
}

export default class UpdateUrlAction extends ChromeMessageAction {
    action = 'updateUrl'
    payload: string
}

export default class UpdateUrlAction extends ChromeMessageAction {
    action = 'updateCount'
    payload: number
}
```

Is there some way to define the payload type without overriding the send method?

Comment: You can checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518125/workaround-for-accessing-class-type-arguments-in-static-method-in-typescript

Comment: @AkashDathan thanks. That worked for me