# typescript return type of instance method

Tags: typescript

how can I infer the return type of an instance method of an extending class? see psuedo code below

Note, this might not be possible, after looking into:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24364
- [Workaround for accessing class type arguments in static method in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518125/workaround-for-accessing-class-type-arguments-in-static-method-in-typescript)

```
// Factory.ts
export default class Factory {
  static make(...params: any[]): FactorySubclass["make"] {
    // @ts-ignore
    return new this(...params).make();
  }

  make() {
    throw new Error("Not implemented");
  }
}

// CarFactory.ts
class CarFactory extends Factory {
  make() {
    return "hello";
  }
}

const instance = CarFactory.make(); // should infer "hello"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for the `instanceof`.

In an execution context, `Factory['make']` refers to the `make` property of the `Factory` class, which in this case is the `make()` static method. In a type context, however, `Factory['make']` refers to the `make` property of the `Factory` *type*, which in this case is the `make()` instance method.

So, this will work as per your requirements:

```
class Factory {
  static make(...params: any[]): ReturnType<Factory['make']> {
    return new this(...params).make();
  }

  make() {
    throw new Error("Not implemented");
  }
}

const x = Factory.make(); // correctly infers the type of x as "void"
```

The [TypeScript 2.1 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) refer to this notation as *indexed access types* or *lookup types*.

```
type m = Factory['make']; // defines the type m as "() => void"
```

---

#### Update

For the updated question, to get the return type of the `make()` method of an extending class to be inferred correctly, you can do so by using a generic parameter to refer to the class type's constructor (see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics)), and making sure that the base class' `make()` instance method's return type is compatible with that of the implementing class, e.g. by making it return `any`:

```
class Factory {
  static make<T extends Factory>(
    this: { new (...params: any[]): T },
    ...params: any[]
  ): ReturnType<T['make']> {
    return new this(...params).make();
  }

  make(): any {
    throw new Error('Not implemented');
  }
}

class CarFactory extends Factory {
  make() {
    return 'hello';
  }
}

const x = Factory.make(); // infers the type of x as "any"
const y = CarFactory.make(); // infers the type of y as "string"
```

Comment: the problem is I need the consumer of the extending class to infer the returned type from the extending class, updated the question

Comment: It's turtles all the way down :) works great! small thing, add the `...params` into `return new this(...params).make()`