# TypeScript generic's type inference fails if generic is used as a callback's argument

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, type-inference

This compiles just fine:

```
class Foo<F> {
  bar: Array<F> = [];

  static create<F, T extends Foo<F>>(this: new () => T): T {
    return new this();
  }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo<string> {}

const foo = Foo2.create();
```

But if I convert `Array<F>` to `Array<(a: F) => void>`, the same code fails:

```
class Foo<F> {
  bar: Array<(a: F) => void> = [];

  static create<F, T extends Foo<F>>(this: new () => T): T {
    return new this();
  }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo<string> {}

const foo = Foo2.create();
      ^^^
The 'this' context of type 'typeof Foo2' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'new () => Foo<unknown>'.
  Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'new () => Foo2' is not assignable to type 'new () => Foo<unknown>'.
      Type 'Foo2' is not assignable to type 'Foo<unknown>'.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'. ts(2684)
```

It works if I type it manually:

```
const foo = Foo2.create<string, Foo2>();
```

So for some reason TypeScript can't infer the `string` type if it's used in a function argument. Why is this?

Comment: `this` is a reserved word, this could make issue

Comment: In static methods it's reserved for this very purpose I believe  @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen it looks like what you want already exists in TypeScript as `ThisType`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why TypeScript is not figuring the type out, but I think you had a few mistakes that you got away with anyway, particularly the `F` type in the method declaration overriding the `F` in the class itself.

Your code can be simplified as follows:

```
class Foo<F> {
  bar: Array<(a: F) => void> = [];

  static create<T>(this: new () => T) {
    return new this();
  }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo<string> {}


const foo = Foo2.create();
```

And it'll work fine:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8sB80DeBYAUNaARmAE4Bc0AgscWAJ5IAUY5sAlNALzoBu8AlgBN0HaAG0AugG5cufBAAuYeX2DRgxAKZKNSACqoG8gBZ8I5AHYaA7tAbsu0Xe2x580TfICuxc9Es3jUztpVwBfXHCcXFBIGAR4ACZoDQAPeQ1zATjEJAViPnMAc3QMSJkcYHhzBWgAM0ROOEQEgDp1LXTgoA)

**Update:** Sorry, I misread the question originally. The answer has since been updated.

Comment: You seem to have tried the first code that works for me as well, my question is about why [the second one doesn't work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8sB80DeBYAUNaARmAE4Bc0AgscWAJ5IAUY5sAlNALzoBu8AlgBN0HaAG0AugG5cufBAAuYeX2DRgxAKZKNKADTQAKtA0APeRoB2AmAmRpUDeQAs+EchY0B3aA3ZdDrORG2Hj40JryAK7EFtAe3s6uvtKhAL646Ti4oJA2iABMxmaW1nCISArEfBYA5ugYmTI4wPAWCtAAZoicZfD5AHTqWubJuEA)

Comment: Sorry about that, @MarkusMeskanen. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to work wonderfully! I had never heard of `ThisType` before, glad to see it exists :)

Comment: No probs. There are a lot of useful utility types you can learn about at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: After trying it in my real code, it no longer works. `ThisType` is not properly typed as a subclass of `Foo`, and therefore I can't call any methods on it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYge2wHkwD4EBvAWACgEERgoAuBAQShgE88AKYRzASgQBeYgDdsASwAmxQQgDaAXQDclStVCQY8BOIB24iJz6MxUlRTUJIwCONhIoAUxuO8AFQAW4sG7YAHR0JOCC8wRl1HAHcEIyFiT29fAIFyKmokbF1IHSyIYF1YRyEECOiQ7yNzdJzrAscAOj0DSstqJwgAVyhdGry6qoQAX0phiwoUNAwcbAAmBEcADwhHXUkp3DxNPQBzYlTqbBFHVikipsMU1oys7GQG5GxtzgByAEl9RGmZ574B0dHVONMtkAGa4YpfeqwJwuSpAA

Comment: This is not using `ThisType`. This is just a generic parameter named `ThisType`...

Comment: I concur with @caTS and edited this answer to remove the reference to `ThisType`.  That cascaded to a few other changes including removing the image of code (such images are [generally not recommended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218) but the only reason I removed this one is because the text in is obsolete).

Comment: I checked the solution for this and found a lot of solutions that work, but none of them support when the parent is generic. Even the creative ones like https://stackoverflow.com/a/52519934/146656. The thing is that in TypeScript you cannot access generic arguments from static methods.